# Which sentence is correct and why: agreement?

Tags: verbs, subjects, objects, agreement

Please tell me which is correct and why:

My favorite thing to smell is flowers.

Or

My favorite things to smell are flowers.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.

**"My favorite thing to smell is flowers,"** means that you like the smell of flowers *in general*.

**"My favorite things to smell are flowers,"** hints more at your sticking your nose into actual blooms. AmE

Comment: Bless you. Thank you for the answer and explination x